# What did "Dr." after a person's or a business's name mean around the turn of the 20th century in the USA?

Tags: united-states, terminology, titles

I am putting together a historical presentation about a late-19th / early 20th-century U. S. ruralite who was involved in many things including operating a general store. I have seen the abbreviation "Dr." on an invoice *after* the name of a business which sold Kodak film to him April 3, 1945. Then I see "Dr." *after* the fellow's name on invoices that were to be issued by the fellow himself. In these cases, what is the meaning of "Dr."?

Comment: It's best if you can include the link, or photo, or a transcript of the documents you're referring to.

Comment: Dr in this context means debit; there will be a corresponding entry labeled CR, which means credit.  The merchant was using a double entry bookkeeping system, which was very common.

Comment: VTC: off topic.

Answer (score -3):

I think it was the abbreviation for drayer and meant the commercial provider of goods or services in the second half of the 19th century .

Comment: Hi and welcome to History SE. Can you back this up with a source?

Comment: Potentially good answer, but would be much stronger if supported by a source.  Can you find an example?  I wonder if google ngram could confirm or deny (I don't have a lot of experience with ngram)

Comment: This seems unlikely, given that *drayer* does not appear in either the 1928 OED or its supplements while all of *dray*, *drayage*, *drayhorse* and *drayman* do. The usage that would presumably attach to *drayer*  was already attached to *drayman*, with as abbreviation an additional sense of *dray* listed in the OED Supplement.